Can't build a map in Rviz
I am trying to build the map for my mobile robot. As you can see in the images attached, in Gazebo the laser's rays hit the walls, but in Rviz it doesn't seem to happen the same thing. 

In Rviz, it seems like there are no obstacles or wall.
I've already run rostopic echo /laser/scan and they publish without problem.
What can I do?
EDIT 1: Could this be a problem of the .stl file I've used to create the world?
EDIT 2: after moving the robot around with teleop and saving the presumed map by running

rosrun map_server map_saver -f cafe2d

This is the image of the map I get:

Clearly, something is wrong. What can I do?

Please, rotate and make sure that the rays are contacting the wall. Also, check the collision tag to see if the walls have it. If not, despite the fact that you see the wall (because of its visual tag) you won't be able to phisically interact with it.
You can simply put a simple box from the ones on the upper bar, which are configured with their collision tag and check if it works.

Yes, I moved the robot a tad to the left and now I can see the laser bumping into the wall. Thanks for the heads up.

Do you happen to know how to avoid the fact that by moving the robot for scanning the whole map, the parts already scanned disappear, thus I can't fully map the whole space.

We need to know the package you are using for creating the map (process called SLAM) and also the configuration used for it. About scanned parts disappearing after going away of them could be because you are not creating a global map and just a local one. Please share the software used and the config file as well

https://github.com/edoardo-cioffi-1997/AMR  This the package of the mobile robot. In a terminal I ran "roslaunch amr spawn_amr.launch" and in a second terminal I ran "roslaunch gmapping gmapping.launch".  This last file is from the slam_gmapping package. Do I need to provide more info?

You would need to understand how gmapping works. I tried to search the launch gmapping.launch in the gmapping package, but didn't find it. Probably you are using another version from the last one published on GitHub. I haven't worked with gmapping and instead used slam_toolbox so I don't know if I can help you more on this.

The gmapping.launch is a file I've built to run the package gmapping. It's in the launch folder.

I have seen several changes of some predefined values from the parameters of the node. Could you create a different config file which contains the same constraints as the one provided in the package, but only change needed topics such as the name of the laser, frame naming if neccessary, and reproduce the demo? Also, since you have control on the Git, could you provide a video launching the node and how the map is created in rviz?

Updated the folder config and launch with original files, they are denoted by the prefix "original_". Unfortunately, I cannot provide a video since my Gazebo crashes while recording. However, my steps are: launch spawn_amr.launch, launch gmapping.launch and then I launch rviz. In rviz I will add LaserScan, RobotModel and Map. To create the map I navigate in Gazebo with rqt_gui and teleop_key.

Your Git repository is incomplete, so I cannot replicate your system. I did try the config file you attached on turtlebot3 and is working as intended. Probably something is messed up in the amr package, so check that odometry, model, etc. are working as expected, and then try gmapping. Also, why use_sim_time param in gmapping_launch.launch is set to false, which is incorrect for the simulation. You need to set everything according to your use case.
